# Does PHP's filter_var FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL actually work?

Tags: php, email-validation

After reading various posts I decided not to use REGEX to check if an email is valid and simply use PHP's inbuilt filter_var function. It seemed to work ok, until it started telling me an email was invalid because I had a number in it.

ie  name@domain.com works, while name2@domain.com doesn't.

Am I missing something or is the `filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)` really quite ineffective?

Comment: testing the existence of a dot in the email address is also necessary. http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-email-validation-filter-var-updated/

Comment: @willdanceforfun Your question is inaccurate.  `name2@domain.com` works fine on all versions of PHP that support `filter_var()`.  Proof:  http://3v4l.org/joLvm

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The regular expression used in the PHP 5.3.3 filter code is based on Michael Rushton's blog about [Email Address Validation](http://squiloople.com/2009/12/20/email-address-validation/).  It does seem to work for the case you mention.

You could also check out some of the options in [Comparing E-mail Address Validating Regular Expressions](http://fightingforalostcause.net/misc/2006/compare-email-regex.php) (the regexp currently used in PHP is one of those tested).

Then you could choose a regexp you like better, and use it in a call to `preg_match()`.

Or else you could take the regexp and replace the one in file PHP/ext/filter/logical_filter.c, function `php_filter_validate_email()`, and rebuild PHP.

Comment: The link to the Michael Rushton's blog now brings you to an empty page :(

Comment: @Matteo, you can find the same code in the PHP source. Or find Michael Rushton's blog in the wayback machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20150910045413/http://squiloople.com/2009/12/20/email-address-validation

Answer (score 5):

name2@domain.com seems to work fine:
http://codepad.org/5HDgMW5i

But I've definitely seen people complaining it's got problems, even on SO. In all likelihood, it does have problems, but so will a regex solution. The email address specifications are very, very complicated ([RFC XXXX](http://code.iamcal.com/php/rfc822/)).

That's why the only solution to verify emails you should rely on is sending an email to the address  and demand action (eg: if it's a registration script ask them to click on a verification link).

Comment: Thanks for that. I will be sending a validation email it would just be nice to have something in place to make sure people don't accidentally throw in obviously wrong characters.

Comment: @Keen I am not saying throw out regex validation out the window; you could validate it and if it fails warn the user (eg: "the computer says your email is invalid, but it ain't very smart. are you sure you want to use this email?")

Answer (score 2):

```
function isValidEmail($email, $checkDNS = false)
{

    $valid = (
            /* Preference for native version of function */
            function_exists('filter_var') and filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)
            ) || (
                /* The maximum length of an e-mail address is 320 octets, per RFC 2821. */
                strlen($email) <= 320
                /*
                 * The regex below is based on a regex by Michael Rushton.
                 * However, it is not identical. I changed it to only consider routeable
                 * addresses as valid. Michael's regex considers a@b a valid address
                 * which conflicts with section 2.3.5 of RFC 5321 which states that:
                 *
                 * Only resolvable, fully-qualified domain names (FQDNs) are permitted
                 * when domain names are used in SMTP. In other words, names that can
                 * be resolved to MX RRs or address (i.e., A or AAAA) RRs (as discussed
                 * in Section 5) are permitted, as are CNAME RRs whose targets can be
                 * resolved, in turn, to MX or address RRs. Local nicknames or
                 * unqualified names MUST NOT be used.
                 *
                 * This regex does not handle comments and folding whitespace. While
                 * this is technically valid in an email address, these parts aren't
                 * actually part of the address itself.
                 */
                and preg_match_all(
                    '/^(?!(?:(?:\\x22?\\x5C[\\x00-\\x7E]\\x22?)|(?:\\x22?[^\\x5C\\x22]\\x22?))'.
                    '{255,})(?!(?:(?:\\x22?\\x5C[\\x00-\\x7E]\\x22?)|(?:\\x22?[^\\x5C\\x22]\\x22?))'.
                    '{65,}@)(?:(?:[\\x21\\x23-\\x27\\x2A\\x2B\\x2D\\x2F-\\x39\\x3D\\x3F\\x5E-\\x7E]+)|'.
                    '(?:\\x22(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0B\\x0C\\x0E-\\x1F\\x21\\x23-\\x5B\\x5D-\\x7F]|(?:\\x5C[\\x00-\\x7F]))*\\x22))'.
                    '(?:\\.(?:(?:[\\x21\\x23-\\x27\\x2A\\x2B\\x2D\\x2F-\\x39\\x3D\\x3F\\x5E-\\x7E]+)|'.
                    '(?:\\x22(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0B\\x0C\\x0E-\\x1F\\x21\\x23-\\x5B\\x5D-\\x7F]|'.
                    '(?:\\x5C[\\x00-\\x7F]))*\\x22)))*@(?:(?:(?!.*[^.]{64,})'.
                    '(?:(?:(?:xn--)?[a-z0-9]+(?:-+[a-z0-9]+)*\\.){1,126})'.'{1,}'.
                    '(?:(?:[a-z][a-z0-9]*)|(?:(?:xn--)[a-z0-9]+))(?:-+[a-z0-9]+)*)|'.
                    '(?:\\[(?:(?:IPv6:(?:(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})|'.
                    '(?:(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9][:\\]]){7,})(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,5})?::'.
                    '(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,5})?)))|'.
                    '(?:(?:IPv6:(?:(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){5}:)|'.
                    '(?:(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9]:){5,})'.'(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,3})?::'.
                    '(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,3}:)?)))?(?:(?:25[0-5])|'.
                    '(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?:1[0-9]{2})|(?:[1-9]?[0-9]))(?:\\.(?:(?:25[0-5])|'.
                    '(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?:1[0-9]{2})|(?:[1-9]?[0-9]))){3}))\\]))$/iD',
                    $email)
            );

    if( $valid )
    {
        if( $checkDNS && ($domain = end(explode('@',$email, 2))) )
        {
            /*
            Note:
            Adding the dot enforces the root.
            The dot is sometimes necessary if you are searching for a fully qualified domain
            which has the same name as a host on your local domain.
            Of course the dot does not alter results that were OK anyway.
            */
            return checkdnsrr($domain . '.', 'MX');
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}


//-----------------------------------------------------------------

    var_dump(isValidEmail('nechtan@tagon8inc.com', true));
    // bool(true)
```

Answer (score 1):

that filter has been revamped recently.
 http://codepad.org/Lz5m2S2N - appears that in version used by codepad your case is filtered correctly

You can also look at  http://bugs.php.net/49576 and http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/ext/filter/logical_filters.c . Regexp is quite scary.