# php send mail to both parties POST collected email address

Tags: php, forms, email

This is probably an easy question but I am not sure the proper syntax.

I am sending an email to my client - but my client also wants that person to receive the emails once they hit submit.

Currently its a POST php form and it works fine - but need to include the POST-email address that was entered into the form.

```
$from_email = $_POST['emailAddress'];

$to = 'owen@gmail.com';
```

AND I have mail($to, $subject, $message, $header..

So how do I rewrite the code:

```
$to = 'owenpiccirillo@gmail.com';
```

to have also send to the email submitted in the form? because this works.

```
$to = 'owen@gmail.com, whatever@aol.com';
```

but this doesnt work....

```
$to = 'owen@gmail.com' .  $from_email;
```

Thanks in advance
-O

Comment: You could also just set a cc in the header parameter

Comment: Was going to say, CC or BCC.

Comment: Additionaly, you could sanitize the email address using a filter:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3722831/does-phps-filter-var-filter-validate-email-actually-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a comma and space in the `$to` concatenation:

**NOT**

```
$to = 'owen@gmail.com' . $from_email; 
// results in 'owen@gmail.comwhatever@aol.com'
```

but **THIS**

```
$to = 'owen@gmail.com, ' . $from_email; 
// results in 'owen@gmail.com, whatever@aol.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

If this works:

```
$to = 'owen@gmail.com, whatever@aol.com';
```

then what exactly is the issue?  The reason this doesn't work:

```
$to = 'owen@gmail.com' .  $from_email;
```

is because there's no comma separating the values.  So it would evaluate to:

```
$to = 'owen@gmail.comwhatever@aol.com';
```

which isn't a valid email address.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `.` is concatenating the two addresses together. So if you do an `echo` or `print_r` you would see something like this:

```
owen@gmail.comwhatever@aol.com
```

You need to add a comma:

```
// Value will be injected into the string with double quotes.
$to = "owen@gmail.com, $from_email";
```

Alternatively, you can use CC and BCC to send copies.