# PHP filter_var and RFC 5322

Tags: php, filter-var, rfc5322

Is the PHP function `filter_var('bob@example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)` validating the email using the standard RFC 5322?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3722831/does-phps-filter-var-filter-validate-email-actually-work

Comment: @MarcB, There isn't anything about RFC 5322.

Comment: which would sort of imply that it ISN'T using it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a comment in the [implementation code of that filter](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/filter/logical_filters.c):

```
void php_filter_validate_email(PHP_INPUT_FILTER_PARAM_DECL) /* {{{ */
{
    /*
     * The regex below is based on a regex by Michael Rushton.
     * However, it is not identical.  I changed it to only consider routeable
     * addresses as valid.  Michael's regex considers a@b a valid address
     * which conflicts with section 2.3.5 of RFC 5321 which states that:
     *
     *   Only resolvable, fully-qualified domain names (FQDNs) are permitted
     *   when domain names are used in SMTP.  In other words, names that can
     *   be resolved to MX RRs or address (i.e., A or AAAA) RRs (as discussed
     *   in Section 5) are permitted, as are CNAME RRs whose targets can be
     *   resolved, in turn, to MX or address RRs.  Local nicknames or
     *   unqualified names MUST NOT be used.
     *
     * This regex does not handle comments and folding whitespace.  While
     * this is technically valid in an email address, these parts aren't
     * actually part of the address itself.
     *
     * Michael's regex carries this copyright:
     *
     * Copyright Â© Michael Rushton 2009-10
     * http://squiloople.com/
     * Feel free to use and redistribute this code. But please keep this copyright notice.
     *
     */
```

and the "original" source is most likely: http://squiloople.com/2009/12/20/email-address-validation/

```
/**
   * Validate an email address using RFC 5322
   *
...
```

So, you have a claim and someone who fixed an alleged error and ...
...beyond that I have no clue ;-)

Comment: The "observed error" isn't actually an error, just a disagreement over how to interpret the standard. I continue to claim that a@b is *syntactically* valid as per the very section quoted above: "In the case of a top-level domain used by itself in an email address, a single string is used without any dots."

Comment: Sorry, I meant alleged ;-)

Answer (score 4):

As the author of the regular expression being used by `filter_var` I can confirm that it doesn't *comprehensively* use RFC 5322 (specifically, it doesn't allow for comments and folding white space).

The article VolkerK links to contains updated validation -- including a more accurate implementation of RFC 5322 as well as an implementation of RFC 5321 (in my opinion the more appropriate standard) -- but `filter_var` hasn't been updated to incorporate the improvements.