# php integrated function form mail validation doesnt work FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL

Tags: php

I have the following script that checks emails and do something with them if they are correct formatted.. I am using `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` for this
Here is the code:

```
if(!empty($_POST['maillist'])){
    $_POST['maillist'] = 'mariatettamanti@gmail.com,
H0889@sofiaertel.com,sdfd@sfs.com,';    

$mails = explode(',',$_POST['maillist']);

foreach($mails as $mail){
if(!filter_var($mail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
 echo $emailErr = $mail." - Invalid email format<br />"; 
}else{
echo 'do job with this mail';
}

}
}
```

As you can see mails are formatted as mails but the function prints only first mail as correct and the rest as wrong.. Why is that? What am I missing? Thanks

Comment: take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3722831/does-phps-filter-var-filter-validate-email-actually-work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is with last comma in your email address. It create and empty value at the end . To avoid  this you use `isset()`

```
if (!empty($_POST['maillist'])) {
    $_POST['maillist'] = 'H0889@sofisadatel.com,info@daddsadyomiaasdmi.com,info@hotsdaelmidasami.com,';
    $mails = explode(',', $_POST['maillist']);

    foreach ($mails as $mail) {
        if (isset($mail) && $mail != "") {// check for empty email
           if(!filter_var(trim($mail), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                echo $emailErr = $mail . " - Invalid email format<br />";
            } else {
                echo 'do job with this mail';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: #Saty, strange, with example of 3 mails it works but with my real mail lists it doesnt.. I started circleing..

Comment: can you please post the value of `$_POST['maillist']`!!

Comment: I added the sample I am testing with.. it consists wrong and correct formatted mails

Comment: #Saty  did you test it?

Comment: check edit use `trim()` in `if(!filter_var(trim($mail), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {`  It will give you desire result.

Comment: I can't believe man.. so stupid error.. Thanks, no it works !